# How do I restore default owner of files in /var/ directory?

Tags: linux, fedora, permissions

Accidentally in */var/* directory I ran `chown root . -R;chgrp root . -R`. Now services like mysql don't start. Is there a way to restore default owner and groups?

If there is no way, what is the default owner and group of */var/lib/mysql* directory and it's files?

Answer (score 6):

`rpm --setperms --setguids` will reset the permissions of packages you specify that may contain files under `/var`, but files in `/var/lib/mysql` are not managed by rpm. Fortunately, they're all owned by `mysql:mysql` so a single `chown` command will fix that.