# MacOsx - Shell - list all .php files and their octal permissions, inside a specifc folder

Tags: command-line, permissions, files, ls

is it possible to list all the ".php" files located into a direcotry and their octal permissions?

I would like to list them like this:

```
775 /folder/file.php
644 /folder/asd/file2.php
etc...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
find /folder -name '*.php' -type f -print0 |
  perl -0 -lne 'printf "%o %s\n", (lstat $_)[2]&07777, $_'
```

See also this related question: [Convert ls -l output format to chmod format](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/71585/22565).

`-print0` is a GNU extension also supported by BSDs like OS/X. GNU `find` also has a `-printf` predicate which could display the mode, but that one has not been added to BSD's `find`.

<sup>(Tested on OS/X 10.8.4 and Debian 7 but should work on any system that has any version of `perl` and `find -print0` which includes all GNU systems and all recent BSDs)</sup>

Comment: i launched this from iside my folder /htdocs but it doesn't works :( do you tryed by yourself?

Comment: @sbaaaang did you replace `/folder` with the real path? If you run from inside the target folder, that will be `.`.

Answer (score 1):

```
find /some/path -type f -name "*.php" -exec sh -c 'stat -f "%p %N" "{}" | sed -E s/^.{3}//' \;
```

This is tested on OS X 10.8.4. The sed pipe just cuts the first 3 characters off the output (filetype). Looks like OS X `stat` doesn't support straight-up octal permission output.

Comment: That assumes filenames don't contain double quote, backslash, dollar, backtick or newline characters and runs one sed, one sh and one stat commands per file.

Comment: Yes, yes it does. I'm making the assumption that `PHP` files aren't likely to contain any of those characters.

Comment: try `stat -f "%OLp %N" file`