# Changing file permissions according to their names

Tags: bash, shell, shell-script, scripting, chmod

I created 512 files, with names made from combinations of permisions
(`r`, `w`, `x`).

I created them like this:

```
touch ./{r,-}{w,-}{x,-}{r,-}{w,-}{x,-}{r,-}{w,-}{x,-}
```

and I want the files to have same permisions as their name indicates,
for example, files `r-x--xrwx` should have permissions `r-x--xrwx`.

I tried to do it like this:

```
for i in *
do
    u=${i:0:3};g=${i:3:3};o=${i:6:3}
    chmod u=$u,g=$g,o=$o -- $i
done
```

Some of the files end up with the correct permissions, but, for
others, permissions don't match the name. How can I fix this?

Comment: Related: [Convert ls -l output format to chmod format](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/71585)

Answer (score 5):

The parameters you're passing to `chmod` include `-` symbols but shouldn't. To fix that, remove the `-` symbols:

```bsh
for i in *
do
  u=${i:0:3};g=${i:3:3};o=${i:6:3};
  u=${u//-/};g=${g//-/};o=${o//-/};
  chmod -- "u=$u,g=$g,o=$o" "$i"
done
```

Answer (score 0):

You may convert the names into an octal number (e.g. 744) and use it to change permissions:

```sh
#!/bin/bash
# touch ./{r,-}{w,-}{x,-}{r,-}{w,-}{x,-}{r,-}{w,-}{x,-}

for filename in *
do
    str="$filename"
    str="${str//-/0}"
    str="${str//[^0]/1}"
    dec="$((2#$str+0))"
    oct="$(printf '%03o' "$dec")"
    #echo "$str $dec $oct : "
    chmod -- "$oct" "$filename"
done
```

The octal number is obtained by:

- change each `-` to a zero `0`, each any other letter by a one `1`.
- convert the binary number to a decimal (because the shell understand only decimal).
- convert the decimal number into octal.
- use the octal number to change permissions.

The -- in the chmod command is because filenames with several dash `-` are confusing to the command, it believes that the filename is an option.