# How can I retrieve the permissions of a file in a certain format?

Tags: files, permissions

I can change the permissions of a file by:

```
chmod 600 ~/.ssh/authorized_keys
```

How can I retrieve the permissions of a file in the same format which is 600?

Comment: Related: [Convert ls -l output format to chmod format](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/71585/convert-ls-l-output-format-to-chmod-format)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`stat(1)` can show many file associated attributes by specifying special format strings to it's `-c` option. In your case, use `stat -c '%a' ~/.ssh/authorized_keys` to receive the same file mode in octal, `600`.

See [it's manual page](http://linux.die.net/man/1/stat) for a full list of supported format modifiers.

Comment: This is Linux-specific, mind you.  *BSD systems also have a `stat(1)`, but with different options.