# equivalent of the GNU stat command for ksh on AIX

Tags: permissions, aix

Can anyone tell the equivalent command for ksh on AIX or do I have to calculate a rwxrwxrwx value into 777 by using a script?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert ls -l output format to chmod format](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/71585/convert-ls-l-output-format-to-chmod-format)

Answer (score 5):

AIX has an [`istat`](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/ssw_aix_71/com.ibm.aix.cmds3/istat.htm) command that gives you the same kind of information as GNU `stat` does, but not in any arbitrary format.

In particular, you can't get the permissions as an octal number directly.

I'm not aware that AIX has dedicated command for that. You can always do it in `perl`:

```
perl -e '@s = stat shift or die "stat: $!\n";
         printf "%o\n", $s[2] & 07777' -- your-file
```

See [Convert ls -l output format to chmod format](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/71585/convert-ls-l-output-format-to-chmod-format) for more details including a way to convert the rwxrwxrwx format to octal.

The above gives you the permissions after symlink resolution. If for symlinks, you want the permissions of the link instead (not very useful as that's always 777), replace `stat` with `lstat`.