# Is it possible to change the directory permission to its previous state?

Tags: debian, permissions, chmod

I have accidentally changed the permission of "/usr/bin" directory and its files by the command:

```
$chmod 775 /usr/bin -R
```

First, there was a problem with sudo but I fixed it. Now I am suspicious that some programs may not run because of changing their permission.

I wonder it is possible to turn back its previous permission?

I am using Debian/testing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most programs in `/usr/bin` should have permissions 755 — readable and executable by all, writable only by their owner, which is root. A few programs are [setuid or setgid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Setuid): they have extra privileges, which are confered by the setuid or setgid bit in the permissions. `/usr/bin/sudo` is one of them; it needs to be setuid root: `chmod 4755 /usr/bin/sudo` restores it.

If you only have official packages from Debian (as opposed to packages in distributions derived from Debian or from other sources), then you can find out which ones contain setuid/setgid binaries by going through the [Lintian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lintian) reports: [setuid](https://lintian.debian.org/tags/setuid-binary.html), [setgid](https://lintian.debian.org/tags/setgid-binary.html), [both](https://lintian.debian.org/tags/setuid-gid-binary.html). In principle, all these packages should come with a file in `/usr/share/lintian/overrides` that declares the setxid binary (the tag “overridden” on these pages indicates the presence of such a declaration), but some packages don't comply (including ubiquitous ones such as`at` and `xserver-xorg`).

The following script prints out a shell script that executes the `chmod` command to restore files in `/usr/bin` to their default permissions, if their default permissions includes the setuid or setgid bit.

```
wget -q -O - https://lintian.debian.org/tags/set{uid,gid,uid-gid}-binary.html |
sed -n 's~^.*> *\(usr/bin/[^ ]*\) \([0-7][0-7][0-7][0-7]\).*~[ -e /\1 ] \&\& chmod \2 /\1~p'
```

In addition, some permissions can be configured locally. These permissions are registered with [`dpkg-statoverride](http://manpages.debian.org/cgi-bin/man.cgi?query=dpkg-statoverride). You can list them with

```
dpkg-statoverride --list '/usr/bin/*'
```

and you can reapply these permissions with

```
dpkg-statoverride --list '/usr/bin/*' |
awk 'system("chmod " $3 " " $4)'
```

If you have packages not from Debian, the only way to be sure to get correct permissions is to reinstall them with `apt-get --reinstall install PACKAGE-NAME`.

Comment: @Giles, 
I have tried the script but there is no change in setuid or  setgid.

Comment: @ofenerci Which script? Note that the `wget … | sed …` snippet only prints out commands to run, it doesn't execute them. Review them, and if you're satisfied, you can run them by adding `| sh` at the end.

Comment: @Giles, I have put `| sh ` at the end of the script below, but I get an _error sh: 1: Syntax error: redirection unexpected_

    `wget -q -O - https://lintian.debian.org/tags/set{uid,gid,uid-gid}-binary.html |
    sed -n 's~.*> *\(usr/bin/[^ ]*\) \([0-7][0-7][0-7][0-7]\).*~[ -e /\1 ] && chmod \2 /\1~p' | sh `

Comment: @ofenerci I shouldn't have tweaked the command after pasting it. I've edited my answer to paste a tested one.

Answer (score 3):

Fortunately those permissions aren't complete destructive, but there is no "undo".

If you can't restore from back-up and you haven't installed anything from source under `/usr/bin` you can potentially use the package manager to recover the correct permissions:

For RPM based distributions (Red Hat Enterprise Linux, Fedora, CentOS etc.) doing so is fairly easy:

```
rpm -a --setperms
```

For dpkg based distributions (such as Debian & Ubuntu)  it appears [slightly less trivial](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/49959/48232) ...

Comment: Note that this doesn't restore setuid (needed for `sudo`) and setgid (needed for `locate`) so those have to be manually fixed. Running `rpm -a --setugids` first might fix this.