# Dealing With A System Which Is Not Letting To LogIn Due To Open Permissions

Tags: permissions, troubleshooting

A colleague of mine told me that after he executed the below command, he's not able to login to the system.

- No user can login via ssh.
- Only normal users can login over physical console of the system, but no administrative commands are allowed, not even

  ```
  # sudo su -
  ```

And the culprit command which did the damage was

```
# chmod -R 777 /
```

My question, of course is, how to deal with such a system? Is there a way to restore the default permissions on a Linux system and what's best way to handle such situations?

Comment: "what's best way to handle such situations?" [Captain's Mast](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mast_(naval)) and a yard-arm. Fixes that problem every single time.

Comment: short answer: unfixable.   but here's a dirty hack that can partially do the job on debian systems http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/49978/7696 - if you use a different unix or distro you may be able to adapt some of the ideas.  or it's probably easier/better to just backup your data & config files and re-install from scratch.

Comment: BTW, ssh is disallowed because the `chmod -R 777` messed up the perms of all `.ssh` directories (including root's) and the files in them.  `ssh` is **very** fussy about perms.  If you want to login via ssh in order to attempt fixing this, the first thing you need to do is fix the home dir perms (`/home/user/` and `/root/`) and the `~/.ssh/` perms.  Also the perms for `/` and `/home`.

Comment: Can you restore from backups?

Comment: @cas thanks, I really understand the consequences of the command. Not to surprise you, It was new thing for me. I tried it on a machine as well, luckily was virtual, but faced same situation.

Comment: @cas there is are backup files, but I'm not sure which folders to be replaced. Is there a way that we could sync the permissions of one system with the affected one?

Comment: @MarkPlotnick thanks Mark! there are backup files, but I'm not sure which folders to be replaced. Is there a way that we could sync the permissions of one system with the affected one?

Comment: If you can restore the backups to a new filesystem,  and mount both the correct and incorrect filesystems on the same computer, you can use `find` to walk through the file tree and run a bunch of `chmod` commands, using the `--reference` option of `chmod` to copy the permissions. I'll see if there's an example online.

Comment: @MarkPlotnick that's much better I think, but do I have to replace every folder one by one or can you suggest a command that would hold reference to all files and folders on newlyinstalled system to apply on the oldsystem? I mean it would be nice, and thanks again Mark!

Comment: @Sollosa I once saw a shell script here (can't find it atm) that would scan a file tree (that had the correct permissions) and produce a shell script containing chmod commands to fix up a similar tree that had incorrect permissions.

Comment: @MarkPlotnick that would be helpful though, thanks anyhow

Comment: Found it on serverfault. The answers there should fix things up: [Copy permissions to identical tree on linux / unix](http://serverfault.com/questions/58277/copy-permissions-to-identical-tree-on-linux-unix)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can't login or su to a root user, the two remaining options are

1. Boot from rescue media, and repair the damage
2. Boot from installer, reinstall the system, then restore data from backups