# Just recursively changed the ownership of "/" to my own user by accident. How screwed am I?

Tags: arch-linux, permissions, recursive, chown

Was messing around with an external drive and wanted to change the permissions of a folder. However, I accidentally ran `sudo chown myuser -r /`. I have never felt so dumb in my life. I immediately realised what I had done and canceled it, but it was too late.

I'm on Arch. How screwed am I. Is this fixable or is it a lesson to be remembered?

Kids this is why you don't mess with recursive commands when sleepy :(.

Comment: If you still have a copy, [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/49959/how-to-restore-default-group-user-ownership-of-all-files-under-var?rq=1) can help you. If you don't have a copy, well… it's a lesson to remember.

Comment: It's fixable with effort, but it might be considerable more work and less reliable than reinstalling. It's also very difficult to judge side effects - I once had a single damaged file, which caused a service fail to start, which in turn caused several other dependent services to corrupt their data. Required a full backup rollback (and code changes to make service failures less catastrophic in the future).

Comment: Thankfully, it's a fresh install. So I'll probably just reinstall.

Comment: Having never made any mistake like this ever. No, honest, never. Ever. Really. So I never do a dummy run with `ls -R ` to check the file list I am about to recursively stamp on, even when regexing to get the file list.

Comment: Short answer: A lesson to be remembered. I think the only real solution for this kind of problem is to restore from backup. So make frequent backups/snapshots.